# Converting JSON data to CSV in Cloudant using List and View

Tags: json, csv, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I tried to convert the JSON data in my Cloudant db to csv format, using the List function. It works perfectly for all values except JSON array values, i.e. the nested values. For these, I am getting [object object] as the output in my csv document.

Please find the sample JSON document which I am using, below:

```
  {
    "NAME": "Aparna",
    "EMAIL": "something@domain.com",

    "PUBLIC_OFFICIALS_CONTACTED": [
    { "NAME_PUBLIC_OFFICIAL": [ "ab"],
    "TITLE_PUBLIC_OFFICIAL": ["cd"]}
    ],
    "COMMUNICATION_TYPE": [
    "Meeting",
    "Phone",
    "Handout",
    "Conference"
    ],
    "NAMES_OF_OTHERS_FROM_IBM": [
    { "NAME_OF_OTHERS": ["ef"],
    "TITLE_OF_OTHERS": [ "gh"]}
    ],
    "COMMUNICATION_BENEFIT": "Yes",
    "LAST_UPDATE_BY" : "ap"
    }

Please find the map and list functions used below :


     "map" : "function(doc){
                                 if((\"SAVE_TYPE_SUBMIT\" in doc) && (doc.SAVE_TYPE_SUBMIT== \"Submit\")) {
                                    emit (doc. LAST_UPDATE_BY,[doc.NAME,doc.EMAIL,doc.PUBLIC_OFFICIALS_CONTACTED[0].NAME_PUBLIC_OFFICIAL,\n   doc.PUBLIC_OFFICIALS_CONTACTED[0].TITLE_PUBLIC_OFFICIAL,doc.COMMUNICATION_TYPE,doc.NAMES_OF_OTHERS_FROM_IBM[0].NAME_OF_OTHERS,  doc.NAMES_OF_OTHERS_FROM_IBM[0].TITLE_OF_OTHERS, doc.COMMUNICATION_BENEFIT,doc. LAST_UPDATE_BY,doc.LAST_UPDATE_DATE]) ;
                                  }
                              }



"list" : "function (head, req) {
                     var row;
                     start({\n headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/csv' }, 
                        });
                     var first = true;
                     while(row = getRow()) {
                         var doc = row.doc;
                         if (first) {
                            send(Object.keys(doc).join(',') + '\\n');
                            first = false;\n }
                            var line = '';
                            for(var i in doc) {
                           // comma separator
                               if (line.length > 0) {
                                  line += ',';\n }
                                  // output the value, ensuring values that themselves
                                 // contain commas are enclosed in double quotes
                                    var val = doc[i];
                                    if (typeof val == 'string' && val.indexOf(',') > -1)                            {
                                         line += '\"' + val.replace(/\"/g,'\"\"') + '\"';
                                     } 
                                   else {
                                       line += val;
                                        }
                                 }
                                 line += '\\n';
                                 send(line);
                             }}"
```

Note : In the map, only the first values have been fetched from the JSON arrays for now, on purpose, to simplify the function.

Please help understand how to fetched the nested JSON values or arrays and download the same in csv format. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to stringify the object you are trying to export and you will get some clue

```
if (typeof val == 'string' && val.indexOf(',') > -1)                            {
    line += '\"' + val.replace(/\"/g,'\"\"') + '\"';
} 
else {
    line += JSON.stringify(val);
}
```

Or even better

```
if (typeof val == 'string' && val.indexOf(',') > -1)                            {
    line += '\"' + val.replace(/\"/g,'\"\"') + '\"';
} 
else if(val instanceof Array){
    line += val.join(',');
}
else {
    line += JSON.stringify(val);
}
```

Comment: Your solution does help me get the JSON array values in my document and since that was my question, I'm selecting this one. The issue is that it is not easy to format this value in the csv as each field is considered part of the string. 
Nevertheless, thank you for your answer! It did help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to change here that might help.  The first thing is that you don't need to emit all the values you want to use, because you can access the document itself from the list when dealing with a view.

With this in mind, the map could have an emit like

`emit (doc.LAST_UPDATE_BY, null);`

With this in place, if you request the list/view with `include_docs=true` then you can refer to the fields in your document inside the `while(row = getRow())` section like this:

`send(row.doc.NAME + ',' + row.doc.EMAIL + '\\n');`

And for the nested documents, try something like:

`row.doc.PUBLIC_OFFICIALS_CONTACTED.0.NAME_PUBLIC_OFFICIAL`

You already referred in another question to the article I'd recommend for a full working example https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/2015/09/22/export-cloudant-json-as-csv-rss-or-ical/ - hopefully this explanation helps also.